# Basement septic plumbing

Tags: plumbing

Could someone tell me what these pipes are? I think they are the old main septic pipe and clean out.  If that is correct shouldn't these be cut off,filled with dirt and cemented over?
Thanks Pat [image]

Comment: `Could someone tell me what these pipes are? ` .. yes, a plumber that you call to your house ... only you can determine what they actually are ... we can only **guess** what they might be

Comment: If you're correct that it's the main septic clean-out, filling it means you're not going to have clean-out access to your main drain which means your next clog could be even more difficult to clear. Of course, filling it will likely _cause_ the clog in your main drain in the first place. If you're simply looking to have it lowered to be flush with the floor so it's not a trip hazard, that's entirely reasonable and I'm sure someone (maybe you) could do that for you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a rough-in for a basement bathroom? I had the builder do one in my basement and didn't install the bathroom for 15 years.